# Is there a way to create a non-null array from a range?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

In Java a simple array can be created by using a traditional for loop:

```
ImageButton[] buttons = new ImageButton[count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   buttons[i] = view.findViewById(BUTTON_IDS[i]);
}
```

A simple conversion to Kotlin yields the following:

```
val buttons = arrayOfNulls<ImageButton>(count)

for (i in 0..count) {
    buttons[i] = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(BUTTON_IDS[i])
}
```

The issue with this is that now each element in the array is optional; which riddles my code with `?` operators.

Is there a way to create an array in a similar manner, but without the optional type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, use the [constructor of `Array`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays):

```
val buttons = Array(count) { view.findViewById<ImageButton>(BUTTON_IDS[it])!! }
```